# Norm of diagonal and orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, orthogonality

I need your expertise in evaluating the following problem:

Let $D \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a diagonal matrix and let $V \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a orthogonal matrix, then it is know that:

- $\left| \left| D \right| \right| _2 = \max_{i \in [d]}\left\lbrace \lambda_i\right\rbrace$, where $\lambda_i$ is the $i^{th}$ eigenvalue of $D$ for every $i \in [n]$.
- $\left| \left| V \right| \right|_2  = 1 $

So what I want to know is the $l_2$ norm of $DV^{\top}$ and the $l_2$ norm of $V^{\top}D^{-1}$?

Comment: Notice that the $\lambda_i$ may be negative. You forgot the absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The norm is the same as the one of D because the map associated with V (or its inverse) is an isometry.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: So, $$ \left| \left| D V^{\top} \right| \right|_2 = \left| \left| D\right| \right|_2 ??$$

Comment: an $l^2$ norm of a matrix $M$ (or its associated transformation) is the supremum of $||Mx||$ taken over vectors with $||x||=1$ - so ask yourself: what is the "longest" image you can produce from a unit vector using your transformation $x \rightarrow DVx$? The $V$ doesn't do anything to the magnitude of a vector, only $D$ has an effect on it - the same as before. The only real difference between D and DV are the eigenvectors.

Comment: Yes, you're right.